Надпись обработки команды
Как я могу сделать так, чтобы когда дс бот отправляет слеш команду писалось не "Отправка команды", а например "Elix думает..."?
Бота пишу на nextcord, но discord.py тоже подойдет.

await ctx.defer()

Спасибо, @denisnumb, разобрался)
